# Inside table rwo I want to keep a selection box in jade

Tags: pug

```
  table.table.table-striped
    thead
      tr
        th(width="10%") Status
        th(width="10%") select
    tbody
      tr
        td {{ Status }}
        td 
          a.select.thumbnail.form-control()
               option(value='1') opt1
               option(value='1') opt2
```

This is not giving me desired output.I want to put a selection box in the 2nd column of the table. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.select` will output `<a class="select">`. Dot `.` is the shorthand for specifying class which comes from CSS. I'm assuming you want to output [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#DOM_Interface) tag in which case you simply have to use `select` (not `a.select`).

```
td
  select.thumbnail.form-control()
    option(value='1') opt1
    option(value='1') opt2
```